# Ease effect when Page loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I want my logo to have the following saturation effect with ease-out once the page loaded. Is this possible? Or does it only works with "hover"? Here is my code:

```
/* CSS*/
     #logo {
        -moz-transition: all 7s ease-out;  
        -o-transition: all 7s ease-out;  
        -webkit-transition: all 7s ease-out;  
        -ms-transition: all 7s ease-out;  
        transition: all 7s ease-out;
        filter: saturate(120%);
        -webkit-filter: saturate(120%);
        -moz-filter: saturate(120%);
        -o-filter: saturate(120%);
        -ms-filter: saturate(120%);
        cursor:default;

        }


     /* HTML */
 <div id="logo">
        <h4>MyLogo</h4>
        </div>
```

Comment: yes you can get this to work on page load with a bit of jquery for lazy, check out `$(document).ready(function() {
 put your css change code here
});` otherwise put a line of javascript at the end right before the closing body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can do that , why not?

for example we gonna do some margin changing to you'r logo with that. 
we make the default margin-top to -50px so the logo won't show on the page and then when the page completely loaded, were gonna use the jQuery to add a class to the logo DOM.

here how :

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $("#logo").addClass("trans");
});
```

and here is the full fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c2d4xv13/

you can take a look at it and of course if you have any further question were here to answer you.

good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I stripped out the browser specific prefixes, but you could go with a CSS animation if you're only concerned with more modern browser support. I also added a random color to show it working.

```
#logo h4 {
    filter: saturate(10%); 
    color: fuchsia; 
    animation: sat 7s ease-out 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sat {
    100% {
        filter: saturate(120%);    
    }
}
```

[example pen](http://codepen.io/beesandtrees/pen/JdEaXQ)